# How do i automate using Midjouney's /imagine?

Tags: automation, discord.py, artificial-intelligence

I have the midjourney AI bot in my discord server (i bought it) and I want to automate a bot to use the /imagine slash command (i have a big JSON file with stuff I want it to /imagine).

maybe using a bot?!?
I prefer to use python

here is what I tried:

- I tried making my bot send "/imagine ...." but it just prints it instead of using the command.

Answer (score 3):

With the new slash commands, discord bots are not able to call other one's, since (unlike before) it's not actually a message that has it's contents "analysed". So you can't automatically call the MidJourney bot with yours.

There is a [wrapper](https://github.com/Wildric-Auric/MidJourney-Wrapper), but not MidJourney's so against their terms and conditions.

Comment: Note: MidJourney is *NOT* the creator of that wrapper.

Comment: Midjourney is actually against boting in their terms and conditions.

Comment: Ok I'll edit that, sorry for the mistake. But the main answer (about slash commands) is still the same

Comment: there is literally a special scope called applications.commands that allows one bot to call another one.   you can directly sesnd a slash command to another bot.   but midjourney blocks them i think.

Comment: @ErikAronesty I will make sure to edit if that is the case, however from reading the Developer Portal, even though the phrase "allows your app to use commands in a guild" makes it vague, it is implied that ```application.commands``` just grants acces to make slash commands, not use them, as shown with "Additionally, if your bot provides Application Commands, you can add applications.commands to the URL's scopes, so that commands will be available in the guild." Please send me an example of the use you speak about, I will gladly analyse it.

Comment: You can employ one of the API layers for the Midjourney Bot in Discord. A free example is [userapi.ai](https://userapi.ai).

There are also paid APIs available, for example, TNL, although its stability has recently been questionable.

Answer (score 2):

I created a tool that can help with this, Effortless Midjourney. It works as a Chrome extension and can automatically generate, scale and save Midjourney images.

Link to Chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/effortless-midjourney/imhcfncgdcokgbbkiphamnngjdlngige

Link to short usage video:
https://youtu.be/vEUV3b1CFmU

Comment: I used this and it saves a TON of time generating prompts. You need to keep the extension running in a browser window but that's understandable as MidJourney doesn't have an API, nor the ability to run a local instance on your GPU

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your own Midjourney account and host it as your own api-service, you could check out projects like Midjourney Proxy (https://github.com/novicezk/midjourney-proxy) on GitHub.

If you are looking for off-the-shelf Midjourney API service, you can check out GoAPI's [Midjourney API](https://www.goapi.ai/midjourney-api?utm_source=bl&utm_medium=so&utm_campaign=bl_so&utm_id=0913): [https://www.goapi.ai](https://www.goapi.ai/midjourney-api?utm_source=bl&utm_medium=so&utm_campaign=bl_so&utm_id=0913)

Comment: There are few services who offer api to midjourney. For example userapi.ai. They even offer inpaint with mask